# Inserting multiple database rows in one query

Tags: php, sql, insert, duplicates

I know this sounds like a duplicate, but I'm not looking to add multiple rows with a single query, I already have that working. The problem is that I need to only insert ONE row.

I have two pieces of code performing these actions.
The first one - on the registration page:

```
$user = DB::getInstance()->insert('users', array(
    'username' => 'Sam',
    'password' => 'password',
    'salt' => 'salt'

));
```

and then a the what actually performs the query in a separate php class:

```
public function insert($table, $fields = array()) {

    $keys = array_keys($fields);

    $values = '';

    $x = 1;



    foreach($fields as $field) {
        $values .= "?";
        if($x < count($fields)) {
            $values .= ', ';
        }
        $x++;
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO {$table} (`" . implode('`, `', $keys) . "`) VALUES ({$values})";
    if(!$this->query($sql, $fields)->error()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}public function query($sql, $params = array()) {
    $this->_error = false;
    if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)) {
        $x = 1;
        if(count($params)) {
            foreach($params as $param) {
                $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
                $x++;
            }
        }

        if($this->_query->execute()) {
            $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
        } else {
            $this->_error = true;
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Quite a bit there, but I just wanted to include everything.  This is currently working, it enters records into my database, the only problem is that it enters 2 each time.

HERES A SCREENSHHOT OF MY DATABASE:

[image]

As you can see from the ID's I've been going over this code for a while now.  I have a feeling something terrifically small is throwing it off but I just can't seem to find it and need help from a fresh pair of eyes.

Comment: Check to be insert is only being called once.  Also consider adding a timestamp to your schema to determine when the inserts occur.

Comment: @kzarns The first line of code I've added is the only time the insert function is called anywhere in the file. And as far as I can tell the first entry happens right when the page first runs, and the second entry comes in once the page has finished loading all its resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it.  I'm running this on Wordpress and the first bit of code I had running the the header.php file.  Turns out that gets run twice on the page at some point and I simply needed to include the code in a "Page" instead.  (but then of course php doesn't want to run on wordpress pages so i needed to use the exec php plugin) but at any rate it's fixed. Thanks